# OS.Walk For loop conundrum on Raspbian

Tags: python, python-3.x, nfs, os.walk

I have a script, initially developed and run on Windows, that I need to run on a raspberry pi.

It had os.walk For loops to identify files of type AVI. Worked fine on windows. However, when running on raspbian, the for loop does not seem to complete and the code is left in running limbo.

One thing to note that it is looping through files on NAS drive mounted using NFS.

I have taken the appropriate code out of my script and run it as a separate py executable, with the same issue. Made some changes to try to get it to work but it always behaves the same.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
    import os
    #with open('/home/pi/Documents/datafile.txt', 'w') as F:
    #for d in os.walk('/home/mnt/cams',topdown=False):
    #    print(str(d))
            #F.write(str(d) + '\n')
    avilist=[[]]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/mnt/cams', topdown=True):
        print("1")
        files = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.']
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d[0] == '.']
        for name in files:
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
            if not ("trash" or "Cameras") in name:
                if name.endswith(".avi"):
                    print(os.path.join(root, name))
                    avilist.append(os.path.join(root, name))
                    print("AVI:  " + os.path.join(root, name))
            else:
                print("trash")
            print("eryes")
        print("erno")
    print ("ermaybe")
```

The end of my output is:

```
1
/home/mnt/cams/trashbox/test.bat
eryes
/home/mnt/cams/trashbox/output.txt
eryes
erno
1
erno
1
erno
1
erno
```

It goes no further. I expected "ermaybe" to suggest the end of the outer for loop, but no matter how long I leave it, it does not complete. Is there any possible issue with NFS mounted folders?

Comment: `if not ("trash" or "Cameras") in name:` is not the way to check for two strings. It should be `if "trash" not in name and "Cameras" not in name:`

Comment: If you want to find all the `.avi` files in a directory hierarchy, use `glob.glob("/home/mnt/cams/**/*.avi", recursive=True)`

Comment: yep, see the mistake with trash or camera. thanks

Comment: However, I had tried glob before and that seems to do the same thing with no output. ```avilist=[[]]
for name in glob.glob('/home/mnt/cams' + "/**/*.avi", recursive = True):
    print("Anything")```    No output in the output shell. Not "Anything". This is why I am wondering if NFS mounts may be the issue. Above works fin in windows with maped network drive.

Comment: Both examples suggest that there are no AVI files there.

Comment: I didn't show the 1st part of output for the initial script where avis were found  ut they were and, logically, that makes no difference to the fact that the for loop was not completing and printing the output that is at the same indentation. If none, it should still finish.

Comment: As for the glob attempt, unfortunately comments do not show indentations and the print statement was outside the for loop so  even if there were no avis (there were...), it should still exit the for loop and print the word "Anything". It did not. Instead it hung as if it was stuck in the for loop. I really think there may be issues with using an NFS mount. Although it is not on the Pi, maybe processing where there are many files externally uses up too much memory so that it cannot get to the end of the files/folders and hangs?

Comment: Sudo mount of the NAS worked so NFS must have had some issues working with my Ras pi

Answer (score 0):

Cannot explain why but NFS seemed to cause the problem. Sudo Mount of the NAS worked and my script read the folder files successfully.